# Simple SQL query, how do I check if a column value starts with the same 5 letters as another column value

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm sure this is simple, please forgive me if so,

I would like to know how to check if the first 5 letters of a column value (eg. `name1`) are equal to the first five letters of another column value eg. (`name2`)

I'm sure something simple like

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE name1*first 5* = name2*first 5*
```

Thank
You

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thank You my database is postgres

Comment: Also, it helps to be precise in your question. Is it possible that both name1 and name2 are, for example, 'a'? Or that they are both NULL? If so, what results are you expecting? My assumptions (name1 and name2 are both non-NULL, and for lengths less than 5, compare the whole string) would give me the same answers you've already got, but I know such assumptions can easily be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T-SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE LEFT(name1, 5) = LEFT(name2, 5)
```

but ANSI form is:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE SUBSTRING(name1 FROM 1 FOR 5) = SUBSTRING(name2 FROM 1 FOR 5)
```

For PostgreSQL, use the ANSI form: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html